# Simulate visualization of mobile device on a desktop one

Tags: ios, testing, safari-web-inspector

I need to test my site on an iOS device from a Mac.
How could one simulate the visualization on a desktop device?

Answer (score 22):

You can use the iOS simulator to do this. You need to enable "Developer Mode" on Safari (Preferences -> Advanced).

Then open the website you want to debug in the iOS simulator. Go back to safari and under Develop you will see the simulator and the tabs open on safari.

If you want to test an actual device, then just plug it into your computer and it should show there too.

That's how I do it.

Comment: Not sure what version of Safari was out when this answer was created. I don't see a iOS simulator in the Develop menu in Safari 11.1, but there is Responsive Design Mode. Unfortunately my company's website uses a cookie for mobile/desktop view though so this doesn't help.

Comment: @EricMajerus Yes, the menu option has changed to mirror some of Chrome's features. However, you can attach an iOS device that has "Web Inspector" enabled and be able to inspect the DOM from your iOS device as opposed as your computer. To enable Web Inspector in your device open [Settings] -> [Safari] -> [Advanced] Then toggle the "Web Inspector" option on. Once you do that, plug it to your computer with a cable and it will appear under the Develop Tab. Select one of the Safari Tabs you have open in your device and Safari will display the DOM. Hope that helps

Answer (score 7):

If you are on Mac OS X just use [Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSSimulator.html). I don't know if it is available by default but it looks like it is a part of the Xcode suite.

Anyway it is free and really useful, it allows you to simulate many popular Apple devices:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can check and use their free trial [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com) , [saucelabs](http://saucelabs.com/) or [browser shots](http://browsershots.org/)
I know this is a very old question and I am answering too late and today there are many options available  but may be someone get this usefull.

Comment: I just went to the browserstack emulator. It said I had 10 free minutes to try it. In 30 seconds I chose iPhone. 10 seconds later, it said my free trial had expired, and presented me with the opportunity to "upgrade". No thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could look into using BrowserStack: http://www.browserstack.com

While not free, it is rather cheap. It allows you to test against several iOS versions on both iPhone and iPad, along with Android, and various desktop browsers and OSs. It has proved quite invaluable to my workplace for doing just these sort of tests.

Comment: Although it says I have "ten free minutes," it said my free trial had expired after about one minute.

Comment: Its cheaper buy iphone than use this commercial annoying site

Comment: Maybe it was cheap back in 2013 but it's definitely not cheap now. I kind of agree with @klvb

Answer (score 3):

You could also download Xcode to your mac and use iPhone simulator.

Answer (score -5):

I use this site mostly

Its good one

http://iphone4simulator.com/

Still its better preferred to test on real device..

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: It contains only an `iframe` that loads the page. Is that good? Try to type "youtube.com". Youtube, for example, doesn't allows to be embeded in a iframe. But, please type "http://stackoverflow.com/" to see what's happening. :-)

Comment: not just the phone but also desktop is this available?

Comment: @John It works good here on my mac machine..

Comment: Why you want such, there is Safari browser where you can test your site for mac os x..

Comment: @P.J, on Ubuntu it doesn't work good...

Comment: It's literally just an iframe. The only thing it "simulates" is the width/height of the phone, but you won't be able to see any iOS-Safari related bugs.

Comment: As said **mpen** is only an iframe that mirrors the phone's size. For the rest does not work with the engine of Safari so it's like if you reduce the window of your browser to the size of a smartphone.