# Simulator to test website on mac IOS desktop

Tags: ios, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulator to test website on mac IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540780/simulator-to-test-website-on-mac-ios)

I need to test my site on a mac ios (desktop not mobile) is there a simulator available online to do this?

Comment: Please don't ask same question again and again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540780/simulator-to-test-website-on-mac-ios

Comment: Second point, its Mac OS X and not mac iOS, Mac OS X is OS for Mac and iOS is OS for iPhone/iPad/iPod. Understand difference first before testing..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iOS simulator to do this. You need to enable "Developer Mode" on Safari (Preferences -> Advanced).

Then open the website you want to debug in the iOS simulator. Go back to safari and under Develop you will see the simulator and the tabs open on safari.

If you want to test an actual device, then just plug it into your computer and it should show there too.

That's how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Testing on Window's Safari browser and testing on Mac OS Safari browser both are same.

Still [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/testing-in-safari-without-a-mac/) is good link that might help you.

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: I don't think that statement is accurate, I just checked on my windows safari and it doesn't look different, although it did when I tested on a mac

Comment: Are version of Safari on Mac OS and Windows machine same?

Comment: well I was using firefox and chrome on mac os and windows, and line-height works differently for example

Comment: Again same thing, check Firefox version if it's same with windows machine?